# Можно ли сделать неактивными часть дат в DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android

Или может кто-то посоветует кастомный диалог, где такое возможно?

Answer (score 1):

Сорцы по большей части открытые. Посмотрите, как устроен диалог внутри - [DatePickerDialog.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9f7936a30bc097c31962891945802507cb4aeb82/core/java/android/app/DatePickerDialog.java).

По коду понимаем, что используется просто DatePicker, который состоит из трех NumberPicker. А для его кастомизации на хабре [написана](http://habrahabr.ru/post/93334/) статья.

Итого имеем следующие пути. Просто пишем наследника DatePickerDialog (или копируем его содержание и делаем свой), в котором просто запрещаем нажимать "ОК", если дата "неверная" (переопределяем метод onClick). Если нужно глубже - то делам на основе [DatePicker](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9f7936a30bc097c31962891945802507cb4aeb82/core/java/android/widget/DatePicker.java) свой кастомный разноцветный NumberPicker.

Answer (score 0):

Если не хочешь кастомизировать, держи такое:

[Learn Android Here- Best working code to set Date limits on Date Picker Dialog,in Android](http://pavantilak.blogspot.ru/2012/11/best-working-code-to-set-date-limits-on.html)